# Is another way to write this APL pattern?

Tags: arrays, design-patterns, apl

### CONTEXT

let `ns` be an unsorted array of unique integers of arbitrary length, return the smallest missing positive number of that array. for example

```
ns = {-1, -3, -2} -> 1
ns = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} -> 10
ns = {-1, 5, 1} -> 2
```

I saw this on an APL youtube video and decided to give it a try myself, my solution is

```
smallestMissingPositive ← {⌊/(⍳⌈/⍪(1∘+)⌈/⍵)~⍵}
```

explanation:

1. the `⍳⌈/⍪(1∘+)⌈/` part is is just all positive number up to N+1 where N is the greatest number in `⍵`. Using a fork to concatenate ⍳⌈/ (a list of positive integers up to the greatest number in `⍵`) with (1∘+)⌈/ (the greatest number in `⍵` plus 1)
2. `~⍵` just takes the difference of the previous point to the original list
3. `⌊/` then finally taking the minimum value on that list

so for `ns = {-1, 1, 3, -2, 5}` first we generate `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` then take the difference of `ns` from that which is `{2, 4, 6}` then taking the minimum element which is `2`.

### QUESTION

Is there a way to optimize my solution further?

### HUNCHES

- I don't even know if my solution is correct or not (i.e. misses a corner case)
- the max-reduce `⌈/` function is used twice in `⍳⌈/⍪(1∘+)⌈/`. the 3-train fork turns `fgh ⍵` into `(f ⍵) g (h ⍵)` but in this particular case the pattern is `(h (f ⍵)) g (h' (f ⍵))` can remove the redundancy in `f`?

Comment: Could you link in the video? I'm a bit confused about the second example and why it's 10 not 1

Comment: yes my mistake, it is 1

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work for the first test case. Also, I think you can do just `{⌊/(⍳(1+⍴⍵))~⍵}` i.e. take the first `length(omega) + 1` integers.

Comment: yeah that pretty much answered it, this question should be closed now

Comment: What APL implementation are you using? On Dyalog, your code gives different answers than the examples you provide. Also, `{⌊/(⍳⌈/⍪(1∘+)⌈/⍵)~⍵}` has no forks in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial idea is almost there, it just needs a little improvement:

```
smp←{⌊/(0<N)/N←⍵~⍨1+0,⍵}
```

Or go full tacit `smp←⊢(0∘<⌊/⍤/⊢)⍤~⍨1+0,⊢`

Let's first prove my solution is correct:

when `⍵` is empty, it gives 1.
when `⍵` has all numbers greater equal than 0, `{⍵~⍨1+0,⍵}` gives all the next numbers of `⍵` that exclude the numbers already in `⍵` give a `⌊/` to the result is just what we want.
when `⍵` are all negative numbers, it gives 1.
when `⍵` is a mixture of negative and positive numbers, the result is still correct.

And if we do a bit equational reasoning,

```
⍵>0 IMPLIES {⌊/⍵~⍨⍳1+⌈/⍵} ←→ {⌊/⍵~⍨1+0,⍵}
```

We can see that you don't need the iota at all!

Still, it is obvious that you are struggling with the binding precedence of APL.

There are a few patterns that could help:

`(XXXX)~⍵` can be written as `⍵~⍨XXXX`

`(1∘+)⌈/⍵` is just `1+⌈/⍵`, and `⌈/1+⌈/⍵` is equal to `⌈/1+⍵`, and there is one thing you get wrong: `⍳⌈/⍪(1∘+)⌈/⍵` is not a fork train! Your original answer didn't use any tacit programming features, `⍪` is just used as a nop there. Only `(f g h) X` with the parenthesis is the tacit train `(f X) g (h X)`, `f g h X` is just plain `f (g (h X))`.

The `(0∘<⌊/⍤/⊢)` I used is derived from the base form `⊢⍤/`.

Comment: thanks, ever since my own answer I have found a shorter answer ```smallestMissingPositive ← {⌊/⍵~⍨⍳1+⍴⍵}```

Comment: `smp←⌊/⊢~⍨1⍳⍤+⍴` saves two more chars.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own Question here, courtesy of user @Dogbert

`smallestMissingPositive ← {⌊/(⍳(1+⍴⍵))~⍵}`

seems like a suitable answer, and as it turns out, my solution was wrong after all.